# Having a problem with a JavaFX extended Scene class if given extended class in constructor

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a class that is an extension of the JavaFX Scene class. However, I would like to provide the option for the user of the class to provide their own existing Scene object which would then gain the additional code that is part of the extended class.

Here is a basic example of what I would LIKE to do:

```
public class MyScene extends Scene {

  public MyScene(Parent root, double width, double height) {
    super(root,width,height);
  }

  public MyScene(Scene scene) {
    super(scene.getRoot(), scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight());
    //This does not work because two Scene objects cannot exist with the same Parent.
  }
}
```

Obviously, the above second class constructor won't work.

I have also tried doing this:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
MyScene myScene = (MyScene) scene;
```

But I get an error saying that I cannot cast scene into MyScene.

Is there any way to do what I am trying to do? And the only reason why I'm trying to do this - it's basically for convenience to whoever is using the MyScene class, giving them the option to pre-build their Scene then use the additional functionality that is in the MyScene class... it would just be a "nice touch" to the class overall.

So is there any way to "cast" or somehow set an existing Scene as the object being extended in the class?

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804937/how-do-i-extend-a-java-class-that-is-instantiated-by-another-class), but I couldn't really understand how to apply the proposed solutions to this situation, especially since javafx.scene.Scene has no default constructor, calling super becomes mandatory in any MyClass constructors.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, but maybe someone else can see something I don't.

Comment: Instead of subclassing, can you use the [_decorator pattern_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)?

Comment: @trashgod Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible for `Scene` either. It has state that cannot be shared between instances (specifically, the `root`) and the methods that query that state cannot be overridden.

Comment: @Michael May I ask, why are you subclassing `Scene` in the first place?

Comment: @Slaw - It's funny you ask that question as I was going over the class and looking at that myself and I guess it just came down to the way I was referencing the various properties and methods in the Scene class. I decided to change the class so that it is not subclassing Scene, then I added a Scene object to the class and instantiated a new Scene object in the class constructor, then any time a reference is needed for a Scene, I just reference that object and it seems to be working out ok. I think that is my only option at this point.

Comment: @Slaw - forgot to mention that there is a class constructor where the user of the class can pass in their own Scene object which I then just set the classes Scene object equal to the one that gets passed in, instead of creating a new one. It works... just not in the way I was hoping I could do it.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the feedback I have been getting, it looks like it is not possible to do what I want to do, so I decided to re-structure the class so that it looks something like this:

```
public class MyScene {

  Scene scene;

  public MyScene(Parent parent, double width, double height) {
    this.scene = new Scene(parent, width, height);
  }

  public MyScene(Scene scene) {
    this.scene = scene;
  }

}
```

Then, of course, where any references are needed to the Scene, I just use the scene object that is defined. It lets me offer the functionality that I'm looking for ... not ideal, but it works.